# How to group by duplicate value and nested the array Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to make a query that will give result, if there is duplicate id it will grouped, and the data below will intact to the same groupped data and it's all in array JSON data.

I make a query like this:

```
SELECT json_build_object(
    'nama_perusahaan',"a"."nama_perusahaan",
    'proyek', json_build_object(
        'no_izin',"b"."no_izin",
        'kode',c.kode,
        'judul_kode',d.judul
    )
)
FROM "t_pencabutan" "a"
LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non" "b" ON "a"."id_pencabutan" = "b"."id_pencabutan"
LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non_b" "c" ON "b"."no_izin" = "c"."no_izin"
LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non_c" "d" ON "c"."id_proyek" = "d"."id_proyek"
```

the result is like below.

```
{
    "nama_perusahaan" : "JASA FERRIE", 
    "proyek" : 
    {
        "no_izin" : "26A/E/IUA/ABC/D8FD", 
        "kode" : "14302", 
        "judul_kode" : "IND"
    }
}
{
    "nama_perusahaan" : "JASA FERRIE", 
    "proyek" : 
    {
        "no_izin" : "26A/E/IUA/ABC/D8FD", 
        "kode" : "13121", 
        "judul_kode" : "IND B"
    }
}
```

what i expect was like this.

```
{
    "nama_perusahaan" : "JASA FERRIE", 
    "proyek" : 
    {
        "no_izin" : "26A/E/IUA/ABC/D8FD", 
        "kode" : "14302", 
        "judul_kode" : "IND"
    }
    {
        "no_izin" : "26A/E/IUA/ABC/D8FD", 
        "kode" : "13121", 
        "judul_kode" : "IND B"
    }
}
```

How could i make a query like my expect ?

Comment: You expected output is not valid JSON format. Are you looking to have a JSON array under key `"proyek"`?

Comment: @GMB yes, i mean like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to turn on aggregation, and use `json_agg()` to generate the proper data structure.

This should be close to what you want:

```
SELECT json_build_object(
    'nama_perusahaan',"a"."nama_perusahaan",
    'proyek', json_agg(
            json_build_object(
            'no_izin',"b"."no_izin",
            'kode',c.kode,
            'judul_kode',d.judul
        )
    )
)
FROM "t_pencabutan" "a"
LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non" "b" ON "a"."id_pencabutan" = "b"."id_pencabutan"
LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non_b" "c" ON "b"."no_izin" = "c"."no_izin"
LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non_c" "d" ON "c"."id_proyek" = "d"."id_proyek"
GROUP BY "a"."nama_perusahaan"
```

Comment: Do you know how to group by again `no_izin` to have nested array for each `kode` and `judul_kode` ? i tried to json_agg the `no_izin` but it didnt work.

So in my question i have duplicate `no_izin`. I want to group by its, so each `no_izin` have nested array of `kode` and `judul_kode`