# How to group by duplicate value of nested array in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Previously question : [How to group by duplicate value and nested the array Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641288/how-to-group-by-duplicate-value-and-nested-the-array-postgresql)

Using this query :

```
    SELECT json_build_object(
    'nama_perusahaan',"a"."nama_perusahaan",
    'proyek', json_agg(
            json_build_object(
            'no_izin',"b"."no_izin",
            'kode',c.kode,
            'judul_kode',d.judul
        )
    )
)
FROM "t_pencabutan" "a"
LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non" "b" ON "a"."id_pencabutan" = "b"."id_pencabutan"
LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non_b" "c" ON "b"."no_izin" = "c"."no_izin"
LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non_c" "d" ON "c"."id_proyek" = "d"."id_proyek"
GROUP BY "a"."nama_perusahaan"
```

The result is shown below:

```
{
    "nama_perusahaan" : "JASA FERRIE", 
    "proyek" : 
    {
        "no_izin" : "26A/E/IU/PMA/D8FD", 
        "kode" : "14302", 
        "judul_kode" : "IND"
    }
    {
        "no_izin" : "26A/E/IU/PMA/D8FD", 
        "kode" : "13121", 
        "judul_kode" : "IND B"
    }
}
```

As you could see, the `proyek` have been nested, so the duplicate `proyek` will be grouped. Now i have to group the same value of `no_izin` so it will double nested array like expected result below.

```
{
    "nama_perusahaan" : "JASA FERRIE", 
    "proyek" : 
    [{
        "no_izin" : "26A/E/IU/PMA/D8FD", 
        "kode_list":[
         {
              "kode" : "14302", 
              "judul_kode" : "IND"
         },
         {
              "kode" : "13121", 
              "judul_kode" : "IND B"
         }]   
    }]
}
```

I tried to use this query:

```
SELECT json_build_object(
    'nama_perusahaan',"a"."nama_perusahaan",
    'proyek', json_agg(
            json_build_object(
            'no_izin',"b"."no_izin",
            'kode_list',json_agg(
                  json_build_object(
                       'kode',c.kode,
                       'judul_kode',d.judul
                  )
             )
        )
    )
)
FROM "t_pencabutan" "a"
LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non" "b" ON "a"."id_pencabutan" = "b"."id_pencabutan"
LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non_b" "c" ON "b"."no_izin" = "c"."no_izin"
LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non_c" "d" ON "c"."id_proyek" = "d"."id_proyek"
GROUP BY "a"."nama_perusahaan", b.no_izin
```

but it didnt work, it gives `ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested LINE 6:'kode_list',json_agg(`. 
What could go wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** It is very hard for us to construct a query without knowing the input data and table structure and have to handle a language we don't know. Please try to **minimize** your further questions (e.g. For your question it is not relevant that you need to join some tables before converting the result into a JSON output), **create examples in English** (handling foreign languages makes the code looking confusing and leads to spelling errors, so the probably right idea fails on writing the words wrong) and **add the input data**! This would help you as well: You would get an answer faster and the chance of code mistakes is much more less (because now without the data we cannot create a runnable example to check our ideas).

---

Creating a nested JSON structure is only possible doing it from the innermost nested object to the outermost one. So first you have to create the `no_izin` array in a subquery. This can be used to create the `proyek` object:

```
SELECT 
    json_build_object(
        'nama_perusahaan',"s"."nama_perusahaan",
        'proyek', json_agg(no_izin)
    )
)
FROM (
    SELECT
        "a"."nama_perusahaan",
        json_build_object(
            'no_izin',
            "b"."no_izin",
            'kode_list',
            json_agg(
                json_build_object(
                    'kode',c.kode,
                     'judul_kode',d.judul
                )
            )
        ) AS no_izin
    FROM "t_pencabutan" "a"
    LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non" "b" ON "a"."id_pencabutan" = "b"."id_pencabutan"
    LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non_b" "c" ON "b"."no_izin" = "c"."no_izin"
    LEFT JOIN "t_pencabutan_non_c" "d" ON "c"."id_proyek" = "d"."id_proyek"
    GROUP BY "c"."id_proyek", "a"."nama_perusahaan"
) AS s
GROUP BY "s"."nama_perusahaan"
```

Comment: thanks! this one works! My apologize with my question, i cant explain my problem so well, lack of sample data, and such... hopefully, i could ask some better next times. Again, thank you very much